# ASP.NET MVC 3 Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

Im having some trouble getting Ajax.ActionLink to work how I expect.

In /views/layout/_Layout.cshtml I load the following scripts

```
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In /views/home/index.chstml I have

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Check Status", "GetStatus", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "status", HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
<div id="status">
Status
</div>
```

And in controllers/HomeController I have

```
   public string GetStatus()
    {
        return "Status ok " + DateTime.Now;
    }
```

When I click the button it takes me to /home/GetStatus And displays Status Ok and the current date and time.

I expected it to simply update the Div area

Comment: So I found the solution here http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/11/17/mvc-3-ajax-redirecting-instead-of-updating-div.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage For anyone else with this problem check the page as it offers multiple fixs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the solution here [Weblogs.asp.net](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/11/17/mvc-3-ajax-redirecting-instead-of-updating-div.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)  For anyone else with this problem check the page as it offers multiple fixs. I basiclly left out reference to a javascript lib.